# git submodule talking about folder that does not exist

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

So I have C++ project in a folder on a git repository in GitHub, the file does not exist locally for me.  I tried deleting it with the command

```
git rm --cached -r foldername
```

but that outputted

```
fatal: pathspec 'foldername' did not match any files
```

Also I have a submodule I was trying to initialize with the following command

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

but it also outputs something about the nonexistant folder

```
No submodule mapping found in .gitmodules for path 'foldername/anotherfolder'
```

I think this is the result of copy pasting a folder with a git repository into this folder a long time ago without initializing it as a submodule.

Anyone have any suggestions?

**EDIT** : So I was able to fix my problem by re-cloning the directory and doing `git -rm foldername` and similar `git rm -rf` on all supposed "submodules".  But I would still like it if someone could explain what exactly was going on here.